# Choosing parameter such that the roots of a cubic polynomial have negative real parts

Tags: inequality, polynomials, roots, cubics

I need to figure out the values of $a\in \mathbb{R}$, which gives roots with negative real parts.

$$P(\lambda) = −\lambda^3 − 3 \lambda^2 + (a − 2) \lambda − 1$$

What technique to apply?

According to the exercise, the correct answer is $a < 5/3$

Comment: Are complex roots allowed? (the question of the language implies this, but I still ask anyway)

Comment: Yes, they are allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Hurwitz criterion after multiplying by (-1) you get

$$G(\lambda)=\lambda^3+3\lambda^2+(2-a)\lambda+1$$

The Hurwitz criterion for a cubic polynomial
$$a_3\lambda^3+a_2\lambda^2+a_1\lambda+a_0$$

says. The real part of the roots is negative if $a_3>0$, $a_2>0$, $a_1>0$, $a_0>0$ and $a_1a_2>a_0a_3$.

From this, we obtain $2-a>0$ (third inequality).

Additionally, we need to have $3(2-a)>1$ (last condition), which implies $2-a>1/3$. Can you do the rest?

Comment: It can be shown, that you do not need all Hurwitz matrices. It is sufficient to check these conditions. If you like you can do the full blown Hurwitz criterion.

Comment: BTW: There are multiple ways of deriving the Hurwitz determinants, which look totally different at the first glance. This is the method that is often used in control theory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the following is correct. And if it is, it is only partial solution.

You are interested for which $a$ the function $f(x)= {x^3+3x^2+2x+1\over x}$ cuts the line $y=a$ only in $x$ with negative real part. Thus all real solutions must be also negative. Calculating the $f'$ we see that it has only local exstremum (minimum) at $x={1\over 2}$ and $y= {23\over 4}$ so for $a\geq {23\over 4}$ the $p$ has solution with positive real part. So $a$ must be smaller then $23/4$

Comment: Can someone please tell me if this was correct reasoning.

Comment: It should be $a< 5/3$

Answer (score 0):

If we restrict our attention to real roots, we can use the intermediate value theorem.

The coefficient of $\lambda^3$ is negative, $\lim_{n\to-\infty}P(\lambda)=\infty$. By the intermediate value theorem, if there exists a $k<0$ such that $P(k)>0$ then there exists a negative real root. This is not just a sufficient condition, but also a necessary one. If a polynomial has a negative real root, then there exists a negative number $k$ such that $P(k)>0$.